# excepción punto nulo kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, recyclerview, nullpointerexception

Estoy teniendo un problema en uno de mis fragments. Tengo un recyclerview cargando información desde firebase. El error se presenta cuando tengo datos almacenados y quiero ingresar pero me muestra el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent, PID: 26915
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.ComidadiaFragment.getBinding(ComidadiaFragment.kt:42)
        at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.ComidadiaFragment.access$getBinding(ComidadiaFragment.kt:34)
        at com.mundomedicos.fitapp.navigationcomponent.fragmentosUsuario.ComidadiaFragment$generar$1.onDataChange(ComidadiaFragment.kt:165)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

revisando las lineas 42 de mi fragment comidadia me encuentro lo siguiente:

```
private var _binding: FragmentComidadiaBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
```

revisando la linea 34 del mismo fragment me señala:

```
class ComidadiaFragment: Fragment(), AdapterComidadia.ClickListener{
```

y en la linea 165 tengo lo siguiente:

```
binding.listadiario.adapter = AdapterComidadia(requireActivity(),lista,this@ComidadiaFragment)
```

mi metodo generar tiene lo siguiente:

```
private fun generar() {
        fechild = formatear(binding.txtfecha.text.toString()).toString()
        ref = database.reference.child("usuarios").child(user).child("alimentacion").child(fechild)//.child("06042022C$reg")//.child("macros")
        ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    lista.clear()
                    for (dt in snapshot.children){
                        val dtcomida = dt?.getValue(Comidadia::class.java)
                        lista.add(dtcomida!!)
                    }
                    binding.listadiario.adapter = AdapterComidadia(requireActivity(),
                        lista,this@ComidadiaFragment)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
```

alguien sabe que proceso o que estaré haciendo mal para que me este devolviendo este tipo de error?

Comment: el error salta cuando haces un click o cuando abre el fragmento ?

Comment: cuando abro el fragment

Comment: `_binding` está en `null`. Quítale el `null` o asegúrate de inicializarlo antes de que se intente acceder a `binding`. Lo mejor que puedes hacer siempre es evitar los valores `null`, haz como si no existieran.

Comment: quite el metodo Destroy() y dejo de salir el error. Muchas gracias por las sugerencias.